# Web Scraper with client-side certs

Tags: certificates, client-side

I am building a web scraper that logs into websites, does some searches and collects results.

The websites I've been logging into right now have all been pretty standard. I have been notified that the program will have to work on computers with client-side certificate. Currently, if you go to the URLs that these computer will eventually be scraping, you get 403 errors.

I have no idea how client certificates work and was wondering if I will
have to change my program in anyway to incorporate these certificates or
will the program just work when run on these computers?

I don't have the ability to use these computers during the production of
my program and I'm trying to mitigate any delays to the production by asking in advance.

Comment: while this question is about certificates, it is, at heart, about programming - migrating to SO